# Plot time series similar to this ggplot export in Power BI

Tags: excel, powerbi

Im trying to generate a graph in PowerBI with this similar concept:
[image]

I am exploring store visitors with COVID lock down periods. I currently have an Excel spreadsheet with sequential dates, sum of daily store transactions and a COVID column where periods of lockdown are equivalent to 1 and those that are not with a 0. I tried using a line and clustered column chart with lines representing store transactions and columns representing the lockdown periods but it was visually too busy since the columns were also separated by day. Any suggestions?

Comment: That sort of formatting and style is not possible with the default visuals. You'll be able to add party of president as a legend, but not the name as you want it. You can use an R visual and ggplot2 to recreate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't likely that there is an existing Power BI visual that does exactly the format you're looking for, which leaves you with a couple of options:

1. Use an [R Visual Script within Power BI](https://medium.com/@MrDataGeek/creating-data-visualizations-in-r-using-power-bi-1ffffac1d598).
2. Create your own [Power BI Custom Visual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/visuals/custom-visual-develop-tutorial).